# C Programming; character pattern recognizing via finite state machine program

Tags: c, pointers, state-machine

I'm building a pattern recognizer program in C that reads in both a user-defined string of characters and a user-defined pattern of 4 characters. The program then has one function to determine if a pattern is found and where the pattern (in terms of the input text index) was initially found.

I know this is elementary to most of you, and I just hope to quickly become a more proficient programmer. When I execute my program it gets stuck in an infinite loop in a manner I don't understand.

I know the issue lies with my FindMatch function and not with the reading in of input text and pattern. What is wrong with my FindMatch function?! Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *getCharBlock(int *size);
int findmatchA(char *text, char *pattern, int tsize, int psize);
void printIt(char *ptr, int index, int size);

int main(){
   char *text, *pattern; //pointers for the characters you will read
   char *p,*q,*r; //some pointer variables
   int tsize,psize,x,y,z; //some integers

   printf("Please input a sequence of character text (characters only will be stored):");
   text = getCharBlock(&tsize);

   printf(" Now input the pattern you seek to search for: ");
   pattern = getCharBlock(&psize);

   x = findmatch(text,pattern,tsize, psize);
   if(x== -1){
      printf("No Match Found \n");
      printf("No starting position for match exists \n");
   }
   else{
      printf("Match Has Been Found! \n");
      printf("Match starting position at index %d \n", x);
      printf("Remaining text after Match: \n");
      printIt(text, x+psize, tsize);
   }


   free(text);
   free(pattern);
}

char *getCharBlock(int *size){
   char *input = (char*) malloc (80*sizeof(char));
   char a;
   int i = 0;
   a = getchar();
   while(i<80 && a!= '\n'){

      if( (a>= 'a' && a <= 'z') || (a>= 'A' && a <= 'Z') ){
         *(input + i) = a;
         i++;
      }
      a = getchar();
   }
   *size = i;

   return input;
 }

 int findmatch(char *text, char *pattern, int tsize, int psize) {
   int index = 0;
   int state = 0;
   while (psize <= tsize) {

     if ((*(text + index) == *pattern) && state == 0){
         state = 1;
         index++;
          printf( "test 1 \n");
     }
     else if ((*(text + index) != *pattern) && state == 0){
          state = 0;
          index++;
          printf( "test1.1 \n");
     }
     else if (*(text + index) == *(pattern + 1) && state ==1) {
       state = 2;
       index++;
       printf( "test 2 \n");
     }
     else if (*(text + index) != *(pattern + 1) && state ==1) {
        state = 0;
        printf("test 2.2 \n");
     }
     else if (*(text + index) == *(pattern + 2) && state ==2) {
        state  = 3;
        printf("test 3 \n");
     }
     else if (*(text + index) != *(pattern + 2) && state ==2) {
        state  = 0;
        printf("test 3.3 \n");
     }
     else if (*(text + index) == *(pattern + 3) && state ==3) {
        state = 4;
        printf("test 4 \n");
     }
     else if (*(text + index) != *(pattern + 3) && state ==3) {
        state = 0;
        printf("test 4.4 \n");
     }
     else {
         return -1;
     }
     index++;
   }
   return index;
   }
```

Comment: `while (psize <= tsize)` neither of those variables is modified in the loop.

Comment: Is the aim to use a statemachine regardless of its applicability as an academic exercise? Because it makes a simple thing very complicated - especially how you have written it.  If the aim is to become more proficient, then you would aim for the simplest and most appropriate solution that works. "pattern recognition" is an AI term - this is just pattern matching - there is no ambiguity.

Comment: Indeed, if the task is to search a string for a substring, I would use `fgets` and `strstr`.

Comment: After `pattern = getCharBlock(&psize);` although you have hard-coded a pattern length of `4` into `findmatch` you didn't check the value of `psize`. For robust user input, the program either checks everything that can be checked, or dies.

Comment: @Weather Vane, I'm confused about how psize and tsize get initialized; though I can check sizes of "strings" by printing them: if the size parameter is the argument to my getCharBlock function, where exactly does size get initialized in my  code (I've modified getCharBlock from provided demos with functions like getLine without fulling understanding what is going on with size therein)? Is psize and tsize initialized inside of getCharBlock and both get to be called by other functions- though they are not being returned by getCharBlock- due to their pointer characteristics? Sorry, still a newb!

Answer (score 1):

> I know this is elementary to most of you, and I just hope to quickly
>   become a more proficient programmer

I wish you luck and I give you my advice.

A few issues prevents program from running properly.

> it gets stuck in an infinite loop in a manner I don't
>   understand.

1) You have forever loop here:

```
`while (psize <= tsize) {`
```

`psize` never changes, it will never reach `tsize` and the loop will never ends.

But that is not the only issue.

2) Input string for `text` and `pattern` is NOT terminated by `'\0'.` Note:
`malloc` is not the `calloc`. The allocated memory can contain any content!
To be prudent you should check, if memory was allocated properly.

3) Not all states properly advance the `index` variable:

```
 else if (*(text + index) == *(pattern + 2) && state ==2) {
    state  = 3;             // sg! index++; is missing!
    printf("test 3 \n");
 }
 else if (*(text + index) != *(pattern + 2) && state ==2) {
    state  = 0;
    printf("test 3.3 \n");
 }
```

That can prevent proper pattern matching.

4) Input verification is not done, E.g.: you should make sure that pattern is exactly `4` characters long.

If I were allowed to give you only one single advice, it would be: `"Never, ever use if-else chain!"`. Replace it with the `switch-case-break` constructs.

Your `int findmatch` is the perfect example. Chain of `if-else` creates jungle hard to debug. Your states are very similar and should create a harmony.
They are not. Your function can be replaced by much more simpler one:

```
int findmatch(char *text, char *pattern, int tsize, int psize) { 
   int index = 0;
   int state = 0;       
   printf("Text=<%s> pattern=<%s> tsize=%d psize=%d \n",text, pattern, tsize, psize);
   while (index <= tsize) {

       switch (state)
       {
           case 0:
                state = next_state(text,pattern, "test 1", "test1.1", &index, 0, 1, 1);
            break;                
            case 1:  // pattern[0]          matched
                state = next_state(text, pattern, "test 2", "test2.2", &index, 1, 2, 0);
            break;
            case 2:  // pattern [0] [1]     matched
                state = next_state(text, pattern, "test 3", "test3.3", &index, 2, 3, 0);
            break;                
            case 3:  // pattern [0] [1] [2] matched
                state = next_state(text, pattern, "test 4", "test4.4", &index, 3, 4, 0);
            break;                
            case 4:
                printf("DONE, index = %d \n",index);
                return index;
            break;                
            default:
                printf("We should not be here! \n");
            break;
       } // case
   } // while       
   return -1;
}
```

Programming is like creating a music or painting. Your creation should be beautiful. Have harmony, and right balance.

This is the working program for your study.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *getCharBlock(int *size);
int findmatch(char *text, char *pattern, int tsize, int psize);
void printIt(char *ptr, int index, int size);

void printIt(char *ptr, int index, int size)
{
}

int main(void){
   char *text, *pattern;    // pointers for the characters you will read
   int tsize,psize,x;       // some integers

   printf("Please input a sequence of character text (characters only will be stored):\n");

   text = getCharBlock(&tsize);

   printf("Now input the pattern you seek to search for: \n");
   pattern = getCharBlock(&psize);

   x = findmatch(text, pattern, tsize, psize);

   if(x == -1){
      printf("No Match Found \n");
      printf("No starting position for match exists \n");
   }
   else{
      printf("Match Has Been Found! \n");
      printf("Match starting position at index %d \n", x - 4);
      printf("Remaining text after Match: <%s> \n", text + x );

      printIt(text, x+psize, tsize);
   }

   free(text);
   free(pattern);
}

char *getCharBlock(int *size){

   char *input = (char*) malloc (80*sizeof(char) +1 );
   if (input == NULL)
   {
       printf("No memory!\n");
       exit(-1);
   }

   char a;
   int i = 0;

   a = getchar();

   while( i<80 &&  a != '\n'){

      if( ((a>= 'a') && (a <= 'z'))  || ( (a>= 'A') &&  (a <= 'Z') ) ){

         * (input + i) = a;

         i++;
      }

      a = getchar();
   }

    * (input + i)  = 0; // sg7! terminate the string 

   *size = i;

   return input;
 }

int next_state(char *text, char *pattern, char *m1, char *m2, int *index, int patternInd, int next_state, int advInd )
{
    int state = 0;

    if (text[*index] == pattern[patternInd]){
        state = next_state;
        printf( "%s\n", m1);
        (*index)++;
    }
    else{
        printf( "%s\n", m2);
        if(advInd)
            (*index)++; 
    }
    return state;       
}

int findmatch(char *text, char *pattern, int tsize, int psize) {

   int index = 0;
   int state = 0;

   printf("Text=<%s> pattern=<%s> tsize=%d psize=%d \n",text, pattern, tsize, psize);
   while (index <= tsize) {

       switch (state)
       {
           case 0:
                state = next_state(text,pattern, "test 1", "test1.1", &index, 0, 1, 1);
            break;

            case 1:  // pattern[0]          matched
                state = next_state(text, pattern, "test 2", "test2.2", &index, 1, 2, 0);
            break;

            case 2:  // pattern [0] [1]     matched
                state = next_state(text, pattern, "test 3", "test3.3", &index, 2, 3, 0);
            break;

            case 3:  // pattern [0] [1] [2] matched
                state = next_state(text, pattern, "test 4", "test4.4", &index, 3, 4, 0);
            break;

            case 4:
                printf("DONE, index = %d \n",index);
                return index;
            break;

            default:
                printf("We should not be here! \n");
            break;
       } // case
   } // while

   return -1;
}
```

Output:

```
Please input a sequence of character text (characters only will be stored):                                                                   
aaabcdef                                                                                                                                      
Now input the pattern you seek to search for:                                                                                                
abcd                                                                                                                                          
Text=<aaabcdef> pattern=<abcd> tsize=8 psize=4                                                                                                
test 1                                                                                                                                        
test2.2                                                                                                                                       
test 1                                                                                                                                        
test2.2                                                                                                                                       
test 1                                                                                                                                        
test 2                                                                                                                                        
test 3                                                                                                                                        
test 4                                                                                                                                        
DONE, index = 6                                                                                                                               
Match Has Been Found!                                                                                                                         
Match starting position at index 2                                                                                                            
Remaining text after Match: <ef>                                                                                                              


Please input a sequence of character text (characters only will be stored):                                                                   
abcdefgh                                                                                                                                      
Now input the pattern you seek to search for:                                                                                                 
efgh                                                                                                                                          
Text=<abcdefgh> pattern=<efgh> tsize=8 psize=4                                                                                                
test1.1                                                                                                                                       
test1.1                                                                                                                                       
test1.1                                                                                                                                       
test1.1                                                                                                                                       
test 1                                                                                                                                        
test 2                                                                                                                                        
test 3                                                                                                                                        
test 4                                                                                                                                        
DONE, index = 8                                                                                                                               
Match Has Been Found!                                                                                                                         
Match starting position at index 4                                                                                                            
Remaining text after Match: <>
```

I hope it helps. If you have more questions please do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: sg7, I had not learned of the switch function until you presented it here, for that I thank you. I was able to complete this program without correcting for the non-terminating condition of my forever loop that you mention in 1). Please see my response to this thread for that scenario. However, you are right that a harmonious program that plays well with itself is more desirable. If that loop never terminates given the conditions of its body, then perhaps I would do better modifying that condition. I will modify my code now thanks to your input as well as that of Bruno Ribeiro.

Comment: @PabloBendiksen Good luck Pablo. I am glad I could help. BTW.  One can find a match  in a string in one line of code. There is a `strstr` function which can do that.  Also, state machines typically use `switch-case` to solve pattern matching.

Comment: Got it sg7, I need to keep track of all the included functions accessible to me. Thank ya!

Comment: Your code is precise and efficient, sg7. Thank you for providing it to me. Only confusion I have is that I see you use 0 as the end delimiter for your read in block of chars but I had been taught to use '\0' as the end delimiter for a "string" in C.  When you say it is not the proper way to terminate an input string and mention calloc may I ask - Since I've only been working with malloc, what is about calloc that allows '\0' to be specified as the terminating character to an input block of chars?

Comment: I had been taught to use `'\0' `. Yes, use it as you are told. The compiler will translate it to `0`.  `calloc ` will fill all the allocated memory with `0` 's.  Since `0` is effectively a terminator you will have it already provided.

Answer (score 0):

I have not read your whole code, I've just focused on your infinite loop problem.

You have a problem in the control condition of the while loop in the findmatch() function. You are checking if psize <= tsize but you never update any of those variables. The only other case that you exit this loop is in the last else case where you return -1, but with this code you never get there (you have an if/else case for every situation and keep coming back to state = 0 in case of not match).

You should check in your while condition for something like:

```
while (state != 4 && index < tsize)
```

Also, when you get the return code from findmatch(), you should check for a return value of 4 to be sure you have a match.

You could also reduce a lot of if's in this function if you used the state variable as an indexer to the pattern string:

```
int findmatch(char *text, char *pattern, int tsize, int psize)
{
    int i, state = 0;

    for (i = 0; state < psize && i < tsize; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] != pattern[state])
        {
            // no match, reset state
            i -= state;
            state = 0;
        }
        else
            // found a match, next state
            state++;
    }

    if (state == psize)
        return i - psize;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: For one thing, this code would miss a match where the input is say `aabcd` and the pattern match is `abcd`.

Comment: @BrunoRibeiro  This is not the expected return behavior for this function. The function `int findmatch` should return index to (the end of ) the found pattern in `text` or  `-1` otherwise.

Comment: @sg7 This was a proposition for a different way of doing it, but I believe you were right and it was not difficult to change it to be like it was specified. I've changed it again. Thanks!

Comment: The problem with the control condition of my while loop was properly addressed by you. And I thank you for this. Though more clunky than your code, I had managed to keep this non-terminating condition whilst still returning proper code in the event of a complete match or in the event of no match. That being said, your concise code is marvelous for me to capture! Thank you very much!!

Comment: @PabloBendiksen I am happy that it helped you in any way. Keep practicing and you will improve quickly.

Comment: @BrunoRibeiro thank you for the change in order to return the index to where the match was found. Question- if I were interested in maintaining pointer notation would it be appropriate to state the following inside the if condition: ( *(text + i) != *(pattern + state));  even though i and state were declared as type int and text and pattern were declared as type pointer to char (char *)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see [x] in this.
Array can be accessed by array pointers. So *state*[0] is 1st char in array. You have state==0 and so on to state==3, that is good but you got to work over arrays.
I'm noob but something like that.
Hope this will help.

Comment: Oh that's because I am using pointer notation and pointer arithmetic as opposed to that of arrays. My understanding is that arrays decay to pointers when passed, anyways, and that higher level languages like C++ and Java still rely on pointer syntax "under the hood". Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I wasn't notice Brunos answer just above mine, and is in direction I was think on.
About pointers; if I would think toward this solution with pointers I would still be focused on how it works under the hood, it manages strings over arrays. So to find matching chars per string it has to be array in some form, maybe at compile time. Dono i just can't think off from array concept.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int Myindex = 0;
char *getCharBlock(int *size);
int findmatchA(char *text, char *pattern, int tsize, int psize);
int findmatchB(char *text, char *pattern, int tsize, int psize);
int findmatchC(char *text, char *pattern, int tsize, int psize);
void printIt(char *ptr, int index, int size);

int main() {
  char *text, *pattern, *text2, *pattern2, *text3,
  *pattern3; // pointers for the characters you will read
  char *p, *r;   // some pointer variables
 int tsize, psize, tsize2, psize2, tsize3, psize3, x, y, z; // some integers

  printf(" \n");
  printf("Please input a sequence of characters (only characters will be "
     "stored ): \n");
 text = getCharBlock(&tsize);
printf("\n");
// printf( "tsize is %d \n", tsize);
 printf(" Now input the pattern you seek to search for: \n");
 pattern = getCharBlock(&psize);
 // printf( "tsize is %d \n", psize);

 x = findmatchA(text, pattern, tsize, psize);
 if (x == -1) {
 printf("\n");
 printf("No Match Found \n");
 printf("\n");
 printf("No starting position for match exists \n");
} else {
printf("\n");
printf("Match Has Been Found!!! \n");
// printf( "%d\n", x);
printf("\n");
printf("Match starting position at index %d \n", x - 3);
printf("\n");
printf("Remaining text after Match: \n");
printIt(text, x, tsize);
}

 // //what should be passed?);
 // looks for a match, returns -1 for failure or an int which is the index to
// the location where the match starts.  the return values can be used to
// determine IF a match was found, and where.
printf("\n");
printf("Now input a sequence of character text for non-contiguous "
     "matching(characters only will be stored): \n");
text2 = getCharBlock(&tsize2);
printf("\n");
printf(" Now input the pattern you seek to search for in a non-contiguous "
     "manner: \n");
 pattern2 = getCharBlock(&psize2);

y = findmatchB(text2, pattern2, tsize2, psize2);
if (y == -1) {
printf("\n");
printf("No match found \n");
printf("\n");
printf("No starting position for match exists \n");
} else {
printf("\n");
printf("Match has been found!!! \n");
printf("\n");
printf("Match starting position at index %d \n", y - 4);
printf("\n");
printf("Remaining text after match: \n");
printIt(text, y, tsize);
}
printf("\n");
printf("Now input a sequence of character text for multiple "
     "matchings(characters only will be stored): \n");
text3 = getCharBlock(&tsize3);
printf("\n");
printf(" Now input the pattern you seek to search for: \n");
pattern3 = getCharBlock(&psize3);

z = findmatchC(text3, pattern3, tsize3, psize3);
printf("\n");
printf("The Number of Matches Is %d \n", z);

free(text);
free(pattern);
free(text2);
free(pattern2);
free(text3);
free(pattern3);
}

char *getCharBlock(int *size) {
// this would fill in the "string" of chars for the passed in char pointer.

char *input = (char *)malloc(80 * sizeof(char));
char a;
int i = 0;
a = getchar();
while (i < 80 && a != '\n') {

if ((a >= 'a' && a <= 'z') || (a >= 'A' && a <= 'Z')) {
  *(input + i) = a;
  i++;
 }
  a = getchar();
}
*(input + i) = '\0';
*size = i;

return input;
}

int findmatchA(char *text, char *pattern, int tsize, int psize) {
 int index = 0;
 int state = 0;
  while (psize <= tsize) {

 if ((*(text + index) == *pattern) && state == 0) {
   state = 1;
   index++;
   //  printf( "test 1 \n");
 }

 else if ((*(text + index) != *pattern) && state == 0) {
   state = 0;
   index++;

   //  printf( "test1.1 \n");
  }

  else if (*(text + index) == *(pattern + 1) && state == 1) {
    state = 2;
    index++;
    //  printf( "test 2 \n");
   }

   else if (*(text + index) != *(pattern + 1) && state == 1) {
    state = 0;
    index++;

    //  printf("test 2.2 \n");
   }

   else if (*(text + index) == *(pattern + 2) && state == 2) {
    state = 3;
    index++;
    //  printf("test 3 \n");
    }

   else if (*(text + index) != *(pattern + 2) && state == 2) {
     state = 0;
     index++;

      //  printf("test 3.3 \n");
   }

   else if (*(text + index) == *(pattern + 3) && state == 3) {
    state = 4;
    index++;
    return index;
    //  printf("test 4 \n");
    break;
   }

  else if (*(text + index) != *(pattern + 3) && state == 3) {
    state = 0;
    index++;

    //  printf("test 4.4 \n");
    }

   else {
    return -1;
   }
  }
   return index;
 }

 int findmatchB(char *text2, char *pattern2, int tsize2, int psize2) { // non-
      //contiguous case
    int index = 0;
   int state = 0;

  while (psize2 <= tsize2) {

 if ((*(text2 + index) == *pattern2) && state == 0) {
   state = 1;
  index++;
  //  printf("test1\n");
  }

else if ((*(text2 + index) != *pattern2) && state == 0) {
  state = 0;
  index++;
  //  printf("test1.1\n");
}

else if (*(text2 + index) == *(pattern2 + 1) && state == 1) {
  state = 2;
  index++;
  //    printf("test2\n");
}

else if (*(text2 + index) != *(pattern2 + 1) && state == 1) {
  state = 1;
  index++;
  //    printf("test2.2\n");
}

else if (*(text2 + index) == *(pattern2 + 2) && state == 2) {
  state = 3;
  index++;
  //    printf("test3\n");
}

else if (*(text2 + index) != *(pattern2 + 2) && state == 2) {
  state = 2;
  index++;
  //  printf("test3.3\n");
}

else if (*(text2 + index) == *(pattern2 + 3) && state == 3) {
  state = 4;
  index++;
  //  printf("test4\n");
  break;
  return index;
}

else if (*(text2 + index) != *(pattern2 + 3) && state == 3) {
  state = 3;
  index++;
  //  printf("test4.4\n");
}

else {
  return -1;
 }
}
return index;
}

int findmatchC(char *text3, char *pattern3, int tsize3, int psize3) {
int index = 0;
int pindex = 0;
int state = 0;
int matchcount = 0;
// printf( "tsize is %d \n", tsize3);

while (index <= tsize3) {
//  printf( "test of inside loop \n");
// printf( "pindex is %d \n", pindex);
// printf( "tindex is %d \n", index);
// printf( " text value is %c \n", *(text3 + index));
// printf( " pattern value is %c \n", *(pattern3 + pindex));

 if (*(text3 + index) == *(pattern3 + pindex) && state == 0) {
  state = 1;
  index++;
  pindex++;
  //   printf( "test 1 \n");
  }

  else if (*(text3 + index) != *(pattern3 + pindex) && state == 0) {
  state = 0;
  index++;
  // pindex++;
  //   printf( "test1.1 \n");
  }

  else if (*(text3 + index) == *(pattern3 + pindex) && state == 1) {
  state = 2;
  index++;
  pindex++;
  // printf( "test 2 \n");
  }

  else if (*(text3 + index) != *(pattern3 + pindex) && state == 1) {
  state = 0;
  index++;
  //  pindex++;
  //   printf("test 2.2 \n");
  }

  else if (*(text3 + index) == *(pattern3 + pindex) && state == 2) {
  state = 3;
  index++;
  pindex++;
  //   printf("test 3 \n");
  }

  else if (*(text3 + index) != *(pattern3 + pindex) && state == 2) {
  state = 0;
  index++;
  //  pindex++;
  //   printf("test 3.3 \n");
  }

  else if (*(text3 + index) == *(pattern3 + pindex) && state == 3) {
  state = 0;
  index++;
  pindex = 0;
  matchcount++;
  //   printf("test 4 \n");

 }

  else if (*(text3 + index) != *(pattern3 + pindex) && state == 3) {
  state = 0;
  index++;
  pindex = 0;
  //   printf("test 4.4 \n");
  }

  else {
  return -1;
  }
 }

return matchcount;
}

 void printIt(char *ptr, int index, int size) {

  while (index < size) {
  printf("%c", *(ptr + index));
  index++;

   }
   printf("\n");
 }
```

Comment: I am afraid that it does not work. Check this:  Please input a sequence of characters :    `aaaabcd`                                    
 Now input the pattern you seek to search for:                                                                                               
`sbcd`                                                                  
Match Has Been Found!!! Match starting position at index `97`  Check why I do this:      ` if (advInd)   (*index)++; `

Comment: Oh man, @sg7 you are all too correct. I do not know what your statement `if(advlnd)(*index)++;` does! And more woefully, I do not understand why findMatchA finds a match and, more disconcertedly, finds this match at index 97.

Comment: `if(advlnd)(*index)++;` advances the index by `1`. But only if needed!  I call `next_state` function `4` times but I advance the index only for the first call. You advance the index almost always. That is wrong. Study how `next_call` is used. It may help you to write smaller code for the repetitive tasks.

Comment: I will study it, thank you very much. Computer Systems is a fun-but pretty tough- course that I'm currently taking. I'm no CS Major or Minor, just getting competencies in programming by taking classes